# How to make Cesium billboard with plugin jQuery?

Tags: jquery-plugins, cesiumjs

I want to make billboard in Cesium using my plugin jQuery. I don't need PinBuilder or Images. 
I am using plugin jQuery in html5:

```
<script>
    $('div').firstPlugin("#C0C0C5");
</script>
```

How can I use this plugin like billboard in Cesium?
Please help me! Thank you!

Comment: What is this plug-in?

Answer (score 0):

Cesium Billboards are based on WebGL textures, and unfortunately there's no quick way to turn HTML DOM elements into WebGL textures.  There have been some efforts to [integrate HTML content in a 3D scene](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2013/04/30/closing-the-gap-between-html-and-webgl/), but these revolve around the use of 3D CSS Transforms, not real WebGL texturemaps, so are not applicable to Cesium Billboards.

The best thing to do is probably to use [Billboard.computeScreenSpacePosition](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Billboard.html#computeScreenSpacePosition) to compute the position of the billboard every frame, and then position your DOM element at that screen location.  This won't give you the correct depth if you have multiple overlapping billboards, but does allow the DOM elements to appear to be anchored to a spot on the globe.